# why promise does not return the updated record

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

When I fill the form, next I send him as object to API NodeJS. Here is execute function

```
.post('/create/card', function (req, res) {
    var rb = req.body,
        obj = {
            query: {
                $set: {
                    ['lists.' + rb.cardIndex + '.cards']: rb.cards
                },
                $push: {
                    activity: { $each: [rb.activity], $position: 0 }
                }
            },
            idBoard: rb.idBoard
        }

    Board.updateBoard(obj)
        .then((updated) => { 
            res.send(updated);
        })
})
```

Board.updateBoard(obj) its called to function inside Board.model

```
module.exports.updateBoard = function (obj) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
    Board.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: obj.idBoard }, obj.query, { upsert: true })
      .then((updated) => { 
        resolve(updated);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      })
  });
};
```

This function after update, should return updated object to first function and she should send response to client but in updated version object is that... Object is returned before update. Could someone tell me why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

findOneAndUpdate Method **always returns old ducument** if document already exist or it returns **null** if document does not exist.

if you want updated document to be return then there is one option available
**returnNewDocument**

**returnNewDocument** :  When true, returns the updated document instead of the original document. default value is **false**.

reference: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/

Comment: Hey Arpan Shah, i changed this line for : 
    Board.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: obj.idBoard }, obj.query, { upsert: true, returnNewDocument : true  })  //////but still is returned old document

Comment: which module you are use for mongodb?

Comment: if it is mongoose then you can use  ->  {new :true}

Comment: U mean here? , { upsert: true, returnNewDocument : true, new : true })

Comment: { upsert: true,  new : true })